# Angular router slash in processed string breaks url matching

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following situation (new to Angular dev)

1. A chunk of data gets returned from the API, and in an `*ngFor` i have the following

`<ion-card-title (click)="showCat(customer.brandname)">{{customer.brandname}}</ion-card-title>`

And the function contains

```
  showCat(name){
    this.router.navigate(["/brandsview/" + name + "/"]);
  }
```

+ the needed modifiers in angular routing.

Problem appears when some items resulting from  `customer.brandname` **already contain slashes**.

So if in an item is, for example, *BMW*, url will have no problem. But when an item like ***BMW/MORIS*** gets passed along, it breaks the url structure.

I have no access to the API endpoints nor to the database, so I can strip slashes locally (though I have to learn how to do that in TS) but then it won't match for the database check when I match it in another component that requires the brandname to match that in the database.

Thoughts/best practices to achieve this without breaking stuff? Thanks.

Comment: Can you `encodeURIComponent(name)` before passing into `navigate`?

Comment: I`ll give that  a go right now. Just a sec.

Comment: @Phix Worked like a charm. I passed it reversed (decode) when sending it to the api and all clear till now. Can you answer so I can give you the accepted answer? Thanks

Comment: Great!  Done deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `encodeURIComponent(name)` before passing to the router.

As you've mentioned you'll need to decode it on the consuming side to get the original string.